# How do you edit CSS in IE Developer Tools?

Tags: internet-explorer-dev

I'm using Internet Explorer's Developer tools to try to debug an issue I'm having with a web page.

When I highlight elements the CSS comes up on the right hand side but I don't seem to be able to add new rules or properly edit the existing CSS.

Trying to add a "display:block" property to a class, I tried to edit an existing rule that didn't matter (background-color:transparent) but as soon as I change it the rule disappears!

Am I missing a trick here somewhere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a quick addition to test and see the effect I do it a bit differently.

With the HTML tab selected choose the "Attributes" panel next to Style, Trace Styes and Layout.

Click the "+" button and begin typing the css style you would like to add. The new style attribute is added automatically in the DOM view panel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it sometimes takes a long time to actually update the page you're viewing. May need to click on different elements and come back to the one you edited to see it change, in my experience

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS is valid or there are not conflicting rules - from what I remember, the last time I used IE Developer Tools, it immediately deletes both invalid tags and unused custom tags in some situations.

Personally I now prefer to use Firebug in Firefox and the Chrome Development tools built in to Chrome - I don't really have a favorite, but I find Firebug better for css/design and Chrome better for cookies/scripts etc.

Comment: The problem is: if I can't add a new CSS rule, how do I change a rule from say `background-color: transparent` to `display: block` without it being invalid along the way? As soon as I type `display` then IE thinks the rule - `display: transparent` - is invalid.

Comment: :S Can you delete/disable/do the checkbox on the other first? (sorry forget which option you get)